# jQueryUI Dialog positioning upon window resize

Tags: jquery

I'm initializing the dialog with position: [900, 58] and it looks good
until I resize the window. Upon window resize to reduce the viewport,
horizontal scroll is introduced since the dialog is still at position
[900, 58]. Can anyone please help provide a solution to make the
dialog reposition or initialize the dialog the right way?

Any help on how to calculate the position based on window size and
trigger position calculations on window resize event are very much
welcome as well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [resize](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/resize) event, figure out the size of the [viewport](http://updatepanel.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/getting-the-page-and-viewport-dimensions-using-jquery/), and size it accordingly.